# MICROSOFT OUTLOOK how to create a rule that copies message to a folder if message is from one of my contacts

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook

I want create a new rule to copy all messages from anyone in my Outlook contacts (ie. People or Favorites button in lower left corner of left-hand Nav pane) to a specific folder.

But when creating a rule I don't see any condition that specifies my Outlook contacts.

If I select "people or public group" then "Next>" doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rule you're looking for is "sender is in specified Address Book".

You reach this via
*New Rule... > Apply rule on messages I receive*.

You need to specify the address-book to use, which in this case would be
"Contacts".

[image]